# Не выполняется запрос MYSQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Делаю такой запрос

```
CREATE TABLE `patients` (
  `card_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `fio` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `sex` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `bdate` date NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) DEFAULT NULL,
  `city` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `adress` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `workpl` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `prof` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `profilp` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `prim` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `medsv` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `pdate` date NOT NULL,
  `ptime` time(6) NOT NULL,
  `csb` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `q` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `b` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `inf` longtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

а он выдаёт мне ошибку

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(6) NOT NULL,
  `csb` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `area` varchar(100) DEFAULT' at line 15
```

Хотя я делаю импорт файла на phpmyadmin (xampp) которого экспортировал из другой версии phpmyadmin тоже xampp

Comment: вопрос к xampp и чем там пользуетесь........ ибо запрос отрабатывает корректно http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/55efb   ........ может быть разные версии стоят....или у файла какая-нибудь кодировка невнятная......... но запрос корректен

Comment: судя по ошибке - не понимает `time(6)`. Видимо, другой движок

Answer (score 0):

Парсер mysql выдаёт ошибку с того места, после которого началась ошибка. Следовательно конкретно в вашем случае ошибка в типе данных `time(6)`.

Возможность указания точности дробных значений time была добавлена в [MySQL 5.6.4](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html). У вас установлена, очевидно, более старая версия.